# jQuery toggle not hiding visible element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a Greasemonkey script, and I have roughly the following:

Javascript:

```
var togglingLink = document.createElement("a");
$(togglingLink)
    .attr('href', 'somelink')
    .html('<div>foo</div><div style="display:none">bar</div>');

$(togglingLink).children().toggle();
// Then I insert it into the page.
```

Which makes this HTML:

```
<a href="somelink">
    <div>foo</div>
    <div style="display:none">bar</div>
</a>
```

The $().toggle() is only making the hidden div visible, it's not hiding the visible div.  What am I missing here?

---

[James' jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734692/jquery-toggle-not-hiding-visible-element#comment29321828_19734692) does work.  But the same code in my Greasemonkey script isn't working.

Per bobek's answer, I also tried changing the divs into spans, and that didn't fix it for me.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/J5Xcs/

Comment: Check your CSS which is applied on toggle target "div".

Comment: Hmm, let me update with more specifics of my usage then.  There must be a quirk between what I'm doing in my script and my example code here.

Comment: Having a <div> inside <a> is not valid.

Comment: @bobek I don't think so

Comment: I didn't know you could pass a `document.createElement` through the jQuery function...

Comment: @hilarudeens http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Comment: @JaceCotton $() takes DOM elements as valid selectors.

Comment: @JaceCotton it's pretty pointless, as you could just do `$('<a />')` to achieve the exact same effect.

Comment: @Keen even with your updated code, it still works  http://jsfiddle.net/ZHAuP/

Comment: @bobek Using block element "div" inside a inline element is semantic violation only. If we want, we can do and by using style we can force browser and we can show. I don't want take this conversation in another way. cool

Comment: @JamesMontagne That's really weird.  I see it work fine in that jfiddle, but it fails in my Greasemonkey script.  Augh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  I was actually running `$().toggle();` prior to appending the element to the page.  This is what was causing jQuery to not toggle as expected.  Once I made it the `$().toggle();` happened *after* appending, then it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

Having a `<div>` inside `<a>` is not valid in HTML < 5 and some browsers might not be able to work with it. Change your `<div>` to `<span>` and see if it works then.

Comment: It seems to be valid in HTML5. Go here http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input then paste `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>a</title></head><body><a><div>a</div></a></body></html>`.

Comment: @wared Yes but not in older versions. If he's doing it in IE8 it might not work.

Comment: I'm doing this in Firefox 24.

Comment: Tried with Firefox 25.0, works fine. Does toggle on other elements (non-nested) work for you?

Comment: @JohannesH. Yeah, toggling random elements in the webpage works fine. For some reason my visible div refuses to hide in my script.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no additional CSS applied in your actual code that might interfere? Depending on how you're telling Greasemonkey/Scriptish to execute the code, it might get loaded afterwards and make that div visible again.  
  
It's clear this is not a pure JS issue if the fiddles work - so some additional background info might help.

Comment: @JohannesH. I'll work on that over the weekend.  It's part of a 150-line script, and I thought I'd pared it down to the key elements here.  Obviously I missed something.